# Does the sigma algebra generated by points include intervals?

Tags: measure-theory

is $[0,1] \in \sigma \left(\{\{x\} : x \in \mathbb{R}\}\right)$?

I feel the answer should be no.

Answer (score 4):

Let 
$$\mathcal C:=\{A\subset\mathbb R, A\mbox{ is countable or }\mathbb R\setminus A\mbox{ is countable}\}.$$
We shall see that $\sigma\{\{x\},x\in\mathbb R\}=\mathcal C$.

The collection $\mathcal C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the singletons, hence 
contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by them. And if $A$ is countable, then $A=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by singletons.